# Java : Map showing error : bad operand type for binary operator "+"

Tags: java, dictionary

Below is my code. i am successfully adding values in Map
but when try to get value of particular key and update it then no value getting

**getting error : bad operand type for binary operator "+"**

```
    Map map = new HashMap();

    System.out.println("Enter the number :");
    int k=sc.nextInt();    
    System.out.println(map.get(k));     

    System.out.println("Enter the value:");
    int v=sc.nextInt(); 

    map.put(k, map.get(k)+v);   //getting error here: bad operand type for binary operator "+"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using generics (you're using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) instead), so the compiler has no idea what type of value is in the map - `map.get(k)` returns `Object` as far as the compiler is concerned, and there's no `+(Object, int)` operator.

Just use generics in your `map` declaration and initialization:

```
// Java 7 and later, using the "diamond operator"
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Or:

```
// Java 5 and 6 (will work with 7 and later too, but is longer)
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

The rest will compile with no problems.

If you're new to generics, see the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and the [comprehensive FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html). You should *very, very* rarely use raw types (almost never). You should be able to configure your IDE or compiler to give you a warning if you do so (e.g. with `-Xlint` for `javac`).

Answer (score 3):

Your `map` is a raw `HashMap`. So, the value can be any type. You can't use `+` operator with any type of object in java.

To overcome this, define a generic map like below

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); //Java 7 version

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); //Java 5 and later versions
```

Here, both key and value are type of Integer, so you can use `+` operator with them

Answer (score 2):

Your map is not using generics.

Do this

`Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();` (assuming you have Java 7+)
`Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();` (assuming you have Java 5+)

When no using generics, the result of `map.get()` is `Object` which of course cannot be used with the `+` operator